# Apache Spark : Load file from local instead of HDFS and Loading local file giving IllegalArguementException

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop2

I am new to Apache Spark and trying to load a file from local file system. I am following Hadoop- The Definitve Guide Book.

Here are the environment variables which i have set:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/bng/Documents/hadoop-2.6.4
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/Users/bng/Documents/hadoop-2.6.4
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar

export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/bng/Documents/mongodb/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$PATH
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/bng/Downloads/googleCredentials

export FLUME_HOME=/Users/bng/Documents/apache-flume-1.7.0-bin
export PATH=$PATH:$FLUME_HOME/bin

export SQOOP_HOME=/Users/bng/Documents/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin

export PIG_HOME=/Users/bng/Documents/pig-0.16.0
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin

export HIVE_HOME=/Users/bng/Documents/apache-hive-1.2.2-bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin

export SPARK_HOME=/Users/bng/Documents/spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
```

And here are the commands which i am executing:

```
 val lines = sc.textFile("Users/bng/Documents/hContent/input/ncdc/micro-tab/sample.txt");
 val records = lines.map(_.split("\t"));
 val filters = records.filter(rec => (rec(1) != "9999" && rec(2).matches("[01459]")));
 val tuples = filters.map(rec => (rec(0).toInt, rec(1).toInt));
 val maxTemps = tuples.reduceByKey((a,b) => Math.max(a,b));
 maxTemps.foreach(println(_));
```

The above sc.textFile commands have the path of my local file system, but some how it is pointing to the hdfs, for which i got the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://172.**.**.168/user/KV/Users/bng/Documents/hContent/input/ncdc/micro-tab/sample.txt
```

So, i thought it would be pointing to my hdfs file system, so i manually added a file in hdfs at the "/user/hive/warehouse/records" location adn tried to execute the following:
    val lines = sc.textFile("/user/hive/warehouse/records");

And all worked fine.

But i wanted to load the file from local system, so after searching on i found that i need to add the "file://" uri, so i tried using the below command:

```
val localLines = sc.textFile("file://Users/bng/Documents/hContent/input/ncdc/micro-tab/sample.txt");
localLines.foreach(println(_));
```

But still, i got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file://Users/bng/Documents/hContent/input/ncdc/micro-tab/sample.txt
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:645)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:529)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1644)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:257)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:910)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:910)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
at $iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
at <init>(<console>:49)
at .<init>(<console>:53)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Please suggest what could be the issue here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the catch, the problem was with the "file://" uri. Inteasd of "file://", i needed to use "file:///" uri and everything worked fine.

Intead of :

```
val localLines = sc.textFile("file://Users/bng/Documents/hContent/input/ncdc/micro-tab/sample.txt");
```

I needed to use the following:

```
val localLines = sc.textFile("file:///Users/bng/Documents/hContent/input/ncdc/micro-tab/sample.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just

```
val localLines = sc.textFile("/Users/bng/Documents/hContent/input/ncdc/micro-tab/sample.txt");
```

without `file://` at the beginning

Comment: I think this will point to `hdfs`. `file://` is necessary in newer spark versions (1.6+ maybe)

Comment: @philantrovert it is not true. I use just absolute path to point files in spark 2.0+ without problems

Comment: also check [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets)